# How do I change ssh settings of a live connection?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have been watching this amazing video [The Black Magic Of SSH / SSH Can Do That?](https://vimeo.com/54505525), and the presenter talks about a method to change ssh settings of a live connection through the ssh console without having to reconnect.

He gets a ssh prompt which he proceeds to use to communicate with the local ssh instance that is running on his Mac. Then he uses this ssh prompt to start local port forwarding.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screengrab]

How do I do the same from Ubuntu?

Edit: Actually it is explained in the video towards the end. But I will keep the QA here so that it may help others. Also I recommend the video if you have an hour (!!!) to spend. It is really informative.

Comment: Well, how does the presenter do it on their mac?

Comment: @terdon I can hear him press something on the keyboard (at 10:15), but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After connecting to a remote machine through `ssh`, press <kbd>Return</kbd> and then <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get this prompt.

See the ["Escape characters" section of the ssh manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ssh.1.html#contenttoc4) for some more special keys.